# Data.table objects turn into data.frame after calling fix()

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Every time I run the command `fix(DT)` on a `data.table`, after closing the fix window, `DT` turns into a `data.frame` object. Is this normal?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a = 1:2, b = 2:3)

> class(DT)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

fix(DT) 

# close the window

> class(DT)
[1] "data.frame"
```

EDIT:

some session info:

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Comment: I think it is normal. `fix` and `edit` are functions to be applied to data frames, not data tables. So they will take a copy of DT, modify it, return it as a data frame, and substitute the original DT with it.

Comment: ... and there is not data.table method for `edit`. So, since a data.table is also a data.frame, `edit.data.frame` is used. It doesn't make sense to work on a data.table using `fix` anyway. Normally the data.set will be way too large for that.

Comment: if you're not worried about efficiency you could write an `edit.data.table` method that wrapped `utils:::edit.data.frame` ...

Comment: ok, thanks! I'm happy with that. can some of you re-write his comment as an answer please?

Comment: @Roland I know. But `fix` it's called by RStudio when you click on anything different then a data.frame in the workspace tab. I wanted to make sure that the underlying processes ( `fix`, `edit`) in pure `R` were correct before raising this to RStudio maintainers.

Comment: Fortunately they've already been told and now about to release the 0.98v or R-Studio, http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/suggestions/1619-datatable-as-data-in-workspace-browser, which displays `data.table` as it does with `data.frame`, (probably calling `View` and not `fix` like now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fix` invokes `edit`. However, there is not data.table method for `edit` (check using `methods(edit)`). Because a data.table is also a data.frame, `edit.data.frame` is used instead and it returns a data.frame as documented.

You could write your own `edit.data.table`, but I don't recommend it, since `data.tables` are often way too big to be edited that way in a sensible way.